# Efficient Linq querying while depending on intermediary results

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following queries:

```
var query1 = from a in aEnumerable select a.ToString();
var query2 = from b in bEnumerable select b.ToString();
var query3 = query1.Union(query2);
```

And during later execution of my code I need to use the results of all queries, I will call `ToList()` on each one.

Is there a way to write this so `query1` is not evaluated twice? (once during `query3.ToList()` and another one during `query1.ToList()`)

Comment: Why not just `.ToList()` query1 straightaway?

Comment: My understanding is that calling `.ToList()` in `query1` straightaway and then doing the same for `query3` will make `query1` to be evaluated twice.

Comment: not if you change your code like so:
`var list1 = (from a in aEnumerable select a.ToString()).ToList();
var query3 = list1.AsQueryable().Union(query2);`

Comment: When you `ToList` `query3` it will iterate over the lists you created from the first 2 queries, but will not iterate over the original enumerables again.

Comment: @zaitsman That doesn't change anything.  It's still going to iterate over the values in `list1` when you iterate `query3`.

Comment: @juharr the question was never to prevent `iteration` it was to prevent double evaluation of the Query which will be achieved. they are two different things, when you're evaluating the query any IO etc. may be performed. When you are iterating over a materialised list you're just having your CPU move around some RAM.

Comment: I'm using the wrong term, I probably shouldn't have said evaluation. My enumerables are actually structures already in memory. I want to know the most effective way to get these results (that is, less iterations, evaluations, and whatever else it's used).

Comment: If you are attempting to avoid iterating more than once, I am not clear on what you mean by "use the results" more than once. If you are "using" a list of something then you are probably iterating over it. If you're using it again, you're iterating again. That's not avoidable. Unless you just want to summarize the totals or counts or something. How do you intend to use the data?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the results are going to be used, I'm interested in the most efficient way to _generate_ the results. Assume the lists from query1, 2 and 3 are going to be returned and I don't know how they are going to be used.

Comment: *My enumerables are actually structures already in memory.* Then why are you referring to them as enumerables? An `IEnumerable<T>` conveys the notion of deferred execution. You could eliminate this ambiguity by calling them collections, or lists, or arrays, or whatever they are. Odds are that these structures implement at least the `ICollection<T>` interface.

Comment: @zaitsman If you run `ToList` on the first query you then have the data in the list and using that in another query will not end up evaluating the first query.  Adding `AsQueryable` does nothing to change that.

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList` when you need to use the results of the queries? Are you going to use the results more than once? If not, you are just wasting time and memory calling `ToList` in the first place. Note also that `Union` only returns distinct results, whereas `Concat` just combines the two - did you mean to use `Concat` or did you need `Distinct` results?

Comment: What efficiency are you looking for? Putting `ToList` as early as possible causes the least evaluation, but uses the most memory. What do __you__ mean by efficient?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I didn't know it represents deferred execution. I used it as the simplest structure that supports iteration. Apart from being misleading, does it change anything? That is, would Linq benefit from knowing a more specific interface?

Comment: @NetMage I usually call ToList before returning or passing as an argument to another method to avoid other code accidentally making the queries be evaluated multiple times. This is hypothetical-ish code (I don't write applications that use databases, I write games so most of the time things are in memory), so `Union` or `Concat` doesn't matter, it's just an example. I'm trying to understand how and when Linq evaluates queries. For example, I don't understand why putting ToList as early as possible in all 3 queries (?) causes the least evaluation.

Comment: The actual types of expressions are often a clue, if not entirely easily found. In general, most expressions of type `IEnumerable<>` implement deferred execution and do not evaluate their lambda parameters until enumerated. Methods that return a single value (e.g. `Count`, `Max`, `Min`) must enumerate, and third party extension methods may force immediate evaluation depending on their implementation (using `yield` defers evaluation). Putting `ToList` on each `query`* means (assuming each is enumerated at least once) they will be evaluated at most once.

Comment: Take a look at the [Count](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#41ef9e39e54d0d0b) LINQ implementation. The enumerable is queried for the `ICollection<T>` interface, so that the `Count` property can be used instead of performing an enumeration.